# Is there a way to return the opposite of a custom Django QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking for a way to return the exact opposite of a custom Django Manager queryset. I am working on a project that has some querysets already defined and I want to get the opposite of these. For simplicity I'll use the example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset). Suppose I had a Book model and a DahlManager that filtered the books by `author='Roald Dahl'`. Inside the DahlManager, let's suppose I have another method `get_childrens_books` that only returns his childrens books, something like `is_for_children=True`. Is there a way to get the opposite of this new method without writing a fully separate filter or method? I want something like `Books.dahl_objects.get_childrens_books().exclude()` or `Books.dahl_objects.exclude(get_childrens_books)`, rather than adding another method to DahlManager. The motivation here is that I can see the potential for adding a lot of code that is repetative. I don't want to be writing a `not_filter` for every `filter` that I write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you are asking with a custom queryset function:

```
class DahlBookQueryset(models.Queryset):
    def oposite(self):
        current_ids = self.values_list('id', flat=True)
        return Book.dahl_objects.all().exclude(id__in=current_ids)

# First, define the Manager subclass.
class DahlBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return DahlBookQueryset(self.model, using=self._db).filter(author='Roald Dahl')

    def get_children_books(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(children=True)

# Then hook it into the Book model explicitly.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    dahl_objects = DahlBookManager() # The Dahl-specific manager.
```

And the query will be `Books.dahl_objects.get_childrens_books().oposite()`.

If you don't understand something feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

django has `exclude()` method for their object managers, but you need to use that during the filtering process. In other words, if you create a queryset before like your `get_childrens_books()` method, you cannot take it's opposite. Instead, you can use`exclude()` on the fly.

Let's say you want to filter Books that are **not** children books. This will work:

```py
not_children_books = Books.objects.exclude(children=True)
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this was one of the things I wanted to avoid. I could make a get_adult_books with this, but it feels redundant to me